# Use JSON_EXTRACT to get value from JSON in Spring JPA Custom Query for custom DTO

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to get value from the JSON column and return custom DTO in spring JPA.

Table structure

```
userId (int)
name (string)
street (string)
zipcode (string)
state (string)
country (string)
meta (JSON)
```

`meta` column contains age for example `{"age": "45"}`

I want to fetch a list of users having `id`, `name`, and `age`. As the data can be huge I created a custom DTO `UserDataDto`

Below is an example of the same:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.model.UserDataDto(userId, name, FUNCTION('JSON_EXTRACT', meta, '$.age')) " +
    "FROM User " +
    "WHERE userId IN (:userIds) ")
  List<UserDataDto> findUsersByIdIn(@Param("userIds") List<Long> userIds);
```

`User` Entity:

```
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long userId;

  private String name;
  private String street;
  private String zipcode;
  private String state;
  private String country;

  @NotNull
  @Convert(converter = UserMetaConverter.class)
  private UserMeta meta;

}
```

`UserMeta` structure:

```
@Data
public class UserMeta {

  private Integer age;

}
```

`UserDataDto` structure:

```
public class UserDataDto {
  private Long userId;
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
}
```

On starting the spring boot application I'm getting

> WARN  | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.db.UserRepo.findUsersByIdIn(List<java.lang.Long>)!

The only solution that I can come up with is using a Native query, any other solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: is `SELECT new com.model.userDataDto(....` valid syntax?

Comment: @f1sh I want to add the result to custom DTO `userDataDto`

Comment: How your entity class looks like?

Comment: @AlperDerya added entity class, please check.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can come up with is using `@NamedNativeQuery` and `@SqlResultSetMapping`

in `User` Entity

```
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
  name = "findUsersByIdIn",
  query = "SELECT userId, name, meta->>'$.age' as age " +
    "FROM user " +
    "WHERE user_id = :userIds",
  resultSetMapping = "UserDataDto"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
  name = "UserDataDto",
  classes = @ConstructorResult(
    targetClass = UserDataDto.class,
    columns = {
      @ColumnResult(name = "userId", type = Long.class),
      @ColumnResult(name = "name", type = String.class),
      @ColumnResult(name = "age", type = Integer.class)
    }
  )
)
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
  private String street;
  private String zipcode;
  private String state;
  private String country;

  @NotNull
  @Convert(converter = UserMetaConverter.class)
  private UserMeta meta;

}
```

in Repository

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("findUsersByIdIn", nativeQuery = true)
  List<UserDataDto> findUsersByIdIn(@Param("userIds") List<Long> userIds);
}
```