# How to write a predicate query in JPA if the column contains jsonb data, match an attribute inside that jsonb data

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jsonb, querydsl, predicate

I have a `jsonb` column to save some extra data of an entity. While querying in that table, I want to filter data based on one field inside the `extra_data` along with some other filters. I am using the JPA `findAll` method with a custom specification in my Spring Boot application.

Here is my **ExtraDataDto**:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ExtraDataDTO {

    private String attendantName;

    private Integer attendantId;
}
```

**Entity class**:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OrderItem extends DateAudit {

...other members

@Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ExtraDataDTO extraData;
}
```

I attempted to use the following specification:

```
Specification<OrderItem> serviceItemSpecification = (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
...other conditions

            if (attendantId.isPresent()) {
                Expression<String> attendantIdExpression = root.get("extraData").get("attendantId");
                predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, criteriaBuilder.equal(attendantIdExpression, attendantId.get()));
            }
};
```

However, it results in the following error:

```
"error": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.extraData] of basic type"
```

I'm using `DataTablesRepository` and the output I receive is as follows, excluding the `attendantId` predicate filter:

```
{
....other fields

    "alternateUPC": null,
    "taxProfiles": null,
    "extraData": {
                 "attendantName": "Aby",
                 "attendantId": 1
                 },
    "orderCustomerId": null,
    "orderDrawerName": null
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: you can use native queries like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57934102/175554) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71679896/175554)